# How to find and edit property of object in the array of an objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects, and I want to find property 'plane: true' in some objects and set it to false. And it just adds to array on the same area as an objects. I tried to use function of angular forEach() but nothing happened. Help please.

```js
this.typeTransport = [
      {
        currentTransport: 'plane',
        changeTransport: 'plane_disable',
        plane: true
      },
      {
        currentTransport: 'train',
        changeTransport: 'train_disable',
        train: true
      },
      {
        currentTransport: 'bus',
        changeTransport: 'bus_disable',
        bus: true
      },
      {
        currentTransport: 'ship',
        changeTransport: 'ship_disable',
        ship: true
      }
    ];

angular.forEach(this.typeTransport, function(value, key){
          angular.forEach(value, function(value, key){
            if(key === 'plane'){
    this.typeTransport[key] == false ? this.typeTransport[key] = true : this.typeTransport[key] = false;
              console.log(this.typeTransport);
            }
          });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that typeTransport is an array and 'plane' is not a property of it, the object inside has the property 'plane'

rename inner forEach to value1,key1

```
 angular.forEach(this.typeTransport, function(value, key) {
 angular.forEach(value, function(value1, key1) {

 if (key1 === 'plane') {
      this.typeTransport[key][key1] = false;
    }
  });
 });
```

As per your condition, you are setting false if true, for which above condition works. If you needed to make true=>false & false=>true, then below condition

```
 this.typeTransport[key][key1] = !this.typeTransport[key][key1];
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution in plain Javascript with [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
var typeTransport = [{ currentTransport: 'plane', changeTransport: 'plane_disable', plane: true }, { currentTransport: 'train', changeTransport: 'train_disable', train: true }, { currentTransport: 'bus', changeTransport: 'bus_disable', bus: true }, { currentTransport: 'ship', changeTransport: 'ship_disable', ship: true }];

typeTransport.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.plane) {
        a.plane = false;
    }
})

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(typeTransport, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This would probably be a good solution if OP would like to change `train: true` to `false` instead of `plane: true` :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two forEach loops.

In the second loop you have to refer to each single item instead the array

```
angular.forEach(this.typeTransport, function(item){
          angular.forEach(item, function(value, key){
            if(key === 'plane'){
    item[key] == false ? item[key] = true : item[key] = false;
             console.log(item); 
             console.log(this.typeTransport); 
            }
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that understand your question but this should work.

```
this.tranportType.forEach(function(tt){
     if(tt.hasOwnProperty('plane') && tt.plane){
        tt.plane = false; 
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some 'old school' :)

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.typeTransport.length; i++) {
  if (this.typeTransport[i].plane == true) {
    this.typeTransport[i].plane = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `angular.forEach`, just change it a little bit:

```
angular.forEach(typeTransport, function(value){
    if(value.plane){
        value.plane = false;
    }
});
```

This way your model will update without having to call `$scope.$apply();`

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/ssw08kLk/1/).